# Alternate configuration file for starpy, asterisk interface library

Tags: python, asterisk

I am using [starpy](http://starpy.sourceforge.net/) to manage an asterisk server. According to the documentation, the easiest way to configure the connection to asterisk is by using a file called `./starpy.conf` or `~/.starpy.conf`, and initialize the application like this:

```
APPLICATION = utilapplication.UtilApplication()
```

The file names are, as far as I can see, not configurable. This works fine when you only have one possible configuration, but as soon as you want to interface to asterisk using different configuration parameters, the only way to do that is to put every program in a different directory. And if you are having several applications in one program, that is not even possible.

Is there any way of specifying the configuration file during the construction phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple inherit from UtilApplication, set config files in **init** and call parent's constructor.

```
class Application(UtilApplication):

    def __init__(self):
        self.configFiles = ['/usr/local/etc/foo/bar.conf']
        UtilApplication.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into other libraries for interfacing with the AMI if this is a severe limitation for you.  There are several available that will fit the bill for Asterisk and Python.

Don't need to try and fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: Could you provide pointers to the other available libraries? My initial request (some months ago), only showed starpy.

Comment: If you could provide references to further libraries other than starpy for this it would be very much appreciated. Like gonvaled all I've found while researching is starpy and it seems to be quite an outdated project.

Comment: StarPy has been getting some updates as of late, actually.  I don't think it's appropriate to call it outdated any longer.  https://github.com/asterisk-org/starpy  And @gnxtech3, really?  Over a configuration file location, you'd dump a whole library?